# How to allow only numbers in user input

Tags: c#

I'm just starting out in C# and I made this pretty simple calculator. First of all, what do you think about my code, is there anything I should improve? Second, when I ask the user to input 2 numbers, how do I make it so he can only type numbers? If the user types a different character the loop gets stuck and the program crashes.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;

namespace App1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool retry = true;
            while (retry)
            {
                retry = true;
                double x1;
                double x2;
                double x3;
                string calc;
                Console.WriteLine("**** Hello, Welcome to Calculator ****");
                Console.WriteLine("Type a number please: ");

                x1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.WriteLine("\n Now type another number: ");
                x2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

                Console.WriteLine("\n Now please select a calculation:(/,*,+/-)");
                calc = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
                if (calc == "*")
                {
                    x3 = (x1 * x2);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Your Numbers equal = " + x3);
                    retry = false;
                }
                else if (calc == "/")
                {
                    x3 = (x1 / x2); Console.WriteLine("\n Your Numbers equal = " + x3);
                    retry = false;
                }
                else if (calc == "+")
                {
                    x3 = (x1 + x2);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Your Numbers equal = " + x3);
                    retry = false;
                }
                else if (calc == "-")
                {
                    x3 = (x1 - x2);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Your Numbers equal = " + x3);
                    retry = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\n Error, please type one of the 4 calculations: ");
                    retry = true;
                }

                //Don't Exit:
                Console.ReadKey();
                //Don't Exit:
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Double.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx) to make sure that the user's input is a valid double. This method has the benefit of not throwing an exception if it receives invalid input.

Usage works like this:

```
double x1;
Console.WriteLine("Type a number please: ");
bool success = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x1);
```

What we are doing here is we are telling C# to attempt to convert the input to a double. If this works, `success` is true and `x1` holds that value. If not, success is false and no exception is thrown.

*NOTE: If this syntax is confusing, give the documentation of the [out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/out-parameter-modifier) keyword a quick read.*

The `success` variable allows you to know if the user entered a number. You can wrap this all up in a loop so that the program only progresses if the user enters a number like so:

```
bool success = false;
double x1;
while (!success)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Type a number please: ");
    success = Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out x1);
}
```

This loop will repeat again and again until the user has entered a number, at which point it will exit and the input will be stored in `x1`. You can repeat this for the second number, as well as for the operation input (addition, multiplication etc).

An extra piece of advice if I may, take a look at C#'s [switch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch) keyword, which saves you from having to chain so many `else if` statements, as well as the [break](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/break) keyword which makes the `retry` variable in your code unnecessary.

**EDIT:** To prevent "Use of unassigned local variable", you're going to have to give your numbers an initial value. Example:

```
double x1 = 0.0;
```

This won't affect the program since, assuming you went with the loop, execution doesn't progress until a valid number has been entered and that value has changed.

Comment: Thank you so much, but not my code says x1 and x2 have no values.

Comment: wonderful, works perfect. Will look into switch statements as well like you said,

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Also, consider using `Console.Write()` instead of `Console.WriteLine()`, so that your program looks cleaner. You can use `Console.Write('\n')` to move to the next line.